# Use file names from specific path as MemberData in xUnit. Convert `IEnumerable<string>` to `IEnumerable<object[]>`

Tags: c#, unit-testing, file, testing, xunit

I wanted to write unit tests for all files in specific path. For example - first run will be for file **x**, second for file **y**, etc.

But I have problem with converting `IEnumerable<string>` to `IEnumerable<object[]>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> ExpectedOutputFiles;

public JsonParserTests()
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, GetOutputDataFolder()));
    ExpectedOutputFiles = files; // <--- Error is here
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(ExpectedOutputFiles))]
public void OutputFile_ShouldBeParsedCorrectlyAsJSON_RFC8259(string filename)
{
    // Test parsing output files with Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json
    var json = File.ReadAllText(filename);
    JToken.Parse(json);
    // System.Text.Json have better default options compatible with RFC 8259 specification
    JsonDocument.Parse(json);
}
```

Is this possible, or should I create `[Fact]` unit test and read files in `foreach` loop?

Comment: The problem is simply that `ExpectedOutputFiles` is an `IEnumerable<object[]>`, and `files` is an `IEnumerable<string>`. xUnit wants an `IEnumerable<object[]>` where each element in the `IEnumerable` is an array of objects, containing all of the parameters to pass to your test method. Your test method has 1 parameter, so each element should be a 1-element object array. I.e. you want `ExpectedOutputFiles = files.Select(x => new object[] { x })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code from the constructor to the static member

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> ExpectedOutputFiles() {
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, GetOutputDataFolder()));
    foreach(var file in files) {
        yield return new object[] { file };
    }
}

//...
```

and return each file in an object array

Reference [xUnit Theory: Working With InlineData, MemberData, ClassData](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/)